# Configure a server with Ubuntu 18 to access it from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, dns

First, thanks so much for taking time reading this question. I am new on linux, and I need some guide.

I basically have a Ubuntu 18 server (AWS EC2). I have the static public IP address and the domain name from godaddy.

The thing is that I am not being able to access my server from the internet using the domain I bought on godaddy. The only way I have to access this server is using the IP Address...

Maybe you can help me answering these questions:

1. I think that nothing should be done on AWS EC2 to accept my new domain. right?
2. Is it enough to have just a "A" record on DNS configuration on Godaddy?
3. Finally, what configuration should be done on Ubuntu 18?

   - When enter "hostname" I get --> "server1"
   - When enter "hostname --fqdn" I get --> "XXXX.com" (the domain I bought on godaddy)
   - When enter "dnsdomainname" I get --> "com"

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I just want my webpage to be accessed by everybody on the internet...

Thanks In advice! :)

Comment: `A` record to the EIP (elastic IP public address) should be all you need. If you `ping` or `dig` your domain from local workstation, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by static IP address from GoDaddy the domain name makes sense.

Normally you would want to attach an ElasticIP address to your instance as the public IP that it is assigned will change when the instance reboots. Then you configure the A record in the GoDaddy domain to point to the EIP address, the TTL is normally about 10 minutes for the DNS to reflect so be patient. (This should be enough).

If it still not working after some time you make sure you have an IGW (internet gateway) attached to the VPC and your Security groups and NACLs allow inbound and outbound traffic.